# Need Help: Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a regex that will parse the string below and STOP exactly at 6.0s. This number, 6.0s, could also be a series of digits like 150 or a decimal like 12.35. "s" can be any letter. The stopping point is the most important

Here's my regex: `[\S+\s]+[\d.\d]+[a-z]?`

My problem is that my regex keeps passing 6.0s and copying the the dash line all the way to "See"

```
15+MM  {NXTW FHR 3153   AB  MABXT YT 197-17 <PA>} | APE 6                   6.0s
------------------------------------------------------------
© Copyright 2012 The Boston Series Group, Inc. All rights reserved. See
```

Comment: Can you not just use `str.partition` ?

Comment: str.partition wouldn't work because I'm dealing with a very long text file. That's just the part I'm having issue with.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Do you want the string `"15+MM ... 6.0s"` as the result?

Comment: Yes, I want everything from `15+MM to 6.0s`

Comment: what settings have you enabled for your regex?

Comment: @JohnySkovdal: What do you mean? just import `re` module, and trying to parse the string above.

Comment: From what you write you are trying to match your string as multiple lines. Why? It seems like the logical block would be one line at a time.

Comment: I mean, are you using the "flags" input? E.g. using `DOTALL` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)

Answer (score 1):

How about **splitting the string across newlines and matching with anything upto a number optionally followed by a decimal, digits and char** :-

```
import re

s = '''15+MM  {NXTW FHR 3153   AB  MABXT YT 197-17 <PA>} | APE 6                   6.0s
------------------------------------------------------------
 Copyright 2012 The Boston Series Group, Inc. All rights reserved. See'''
m = re.match(r'.+\d+(\.\d+)?[a-z]?', s.split('\n')[0])
print m.group(0)
```

Output :-

```
C:\>python st.py
15+MM  {NXTW FHR 3153   AB  MABXT YT 197-17 <PA>} | APE 6                   6.0s
```

**Or perhaps using the dashes as delimiters by saying just :-**

```
import re

m = re.match(r'(.*?)\s+-----', s)
print m.group(1)
```

Comment: It has to stop at `6.0s`. not `6`

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're using `[]` to group things — this is a character class (an "any of these characters" construct). Instead you'll want to use `()`.

But instead, try something like `^\S+\s.+\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]?$` — the `^` and `$` are for the start and end of a line, and it sounds like you don't need capture groups at all.

Comment: @jtbandes: Remember to make the decimal part optional `(?:\.\d+)?`.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a line that starts with a series of numbers, characters or `+`, then anything up to a floating number followed by a `s`

```
^[0-9A-Z+]+\s+.*\s+[0-9.]+s$
```

You should also make sure your regex isn't multi-line.

Comment: Following your (@Mike) latest edit, wouldn't the above work for you if you make `s` an optional character instead (`[a-z]?`)?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified anything about the text in front of your `6.0s` group, so there is no reasonable way to create reliable regular expression parts for it. The only thing that is clearly specified is the end. Having said that, this example would print all lines that end with something like `6.0s` as in your specification:

```
for line in opened_file:
    mat = re.search("^.*\s(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-zA-Z])$", line)
    if mat is not None:
        print mat.group(1)
```

The only assumption is that there is some whitespace in front of it which I guessed from what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I used `re.search()` because it searches the entire string, not by each line. Read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

s = '''
15+MM  {NXTW FHR 3153   AB  MABXT YT 197-17 <PA>} | APE 6                   6.0s
------------------------------------------------------------
© Copyright 2012 The Boston Series Group, Inc. All rights reserved. See
'''

m = re.search('.+\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-zA-Z]{1}', s)
if m != None: print m.group(0)
```

Output:

```
15+MM  {NXTW FHR 3153   AB  MABXT YT 197-17 <PA>} | APE 6                   6.0s
```